# Unable to Authenticate to SFTP server from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to create a link service to an SFTP server. When I test the connection I get the error:

[image]

I believe the failed connection is because sftp server does not recognize the Azure Integration Runtime IP address. I say this because I can successfully connect using any SFTP client such as WinSCP.

Therefore, can someone let me know how to obtain the Azure Integration Runtime IP address please?
My Link Service looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Is it On-premise SFTP erver?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for reaching out. No its online/cloud based SFTP server.

Comment: The name of the server is xxxxx.hosting.xxxxx.com

Comment: Can I get your throughts as to whether you think the issue is related to the Azure Integration Runtime IP address please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error, If access is restricted to IPs that are not whitelisted in your SFTP server's firewall rules, it may be connected to a firewall issue. Make sure you whitelist such IPs. Adding [Azure Integration Runtime IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses) to the allow list is an option if you're utilizing Azure IR.

> can someone let me know how to obtain the Azure Integration Runtime IP address please?

To get the Azure IP ranges you can follow this doc [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#discover-service-tags-by-using-downloadable-json-files)

> As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory),
>
> **maxConcurrentConnections** : The upper limit of concurrent connections established to the data store during the activity run. Specify a value only when you want to limit concurrent connections.

You can adjust your Source's and sink's **Max concurrent connection** value to be lower than the SFTP concurrent connection limit set by the SFTP admin.